# Could a perfect squared square be split into two perfect squared squares?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, puzzle

This is a geometric puzzle though it might conceivably 
also define a special class of Pythagorean triples.

A *perfect squared square* PSS is a square (as a plane figure) 
partitioned into smaller squares, each of a different size. 
There are other types of squared squares or 
squared rectangles that have been studied (e.g. simple SPSS, vs compound CPSS), see 
[`wikipedia`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square), [`wolfram`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectSquareDissection.html), and [`squaring.net`](http://www.squaring.net/sq/ss/ss.html).

Question. Is there a perfect squared square that 
can be split into two perfect squared squares? 
That is, could we use the building blocks (smaller squares) 
that form the given perfect squared square to 
form two smaller perfect squared squares?

Of course if the given perfect squared square 
has side $c$ and the two smaller ones have 
sides $a$ and $b$ respectively, then the numbers 
$a$, $b$, $c$ would form a Pythagorean triple 
(since the areas of the two smaller squared squares 
sum up to the area of the given bigger squared square).

Question. Which Pythagorean triples (if any) 
could be represented in the above form?

For some Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ the numbers $(a^2,b^2,c^2)$ 
seem to sometimes appear as *the sides* of neighboring smaller 
squares forming the partition of a perfect squared square. 
For example, for the Pythagorean triple $(3,4,5)$ the 
squared numbers are $(9,16,25)$ and these appear as 
*the sides* of three neighboring squares from the partition 
of the Lowest-order perfect squared square (i.e. formed by only 21 squares which is smallest possible for SPSS, same links as above). 
Could one say anything more about this (an explanation, or 
a description when it occurs, for which Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$)?

Interestingly, a simple geometric argument shows that 
the analogue in three or more dimensions of squaring the square 
has no solutions, e.g. one cannot partition a cube 
(as a three-dimensional geometric figure) into smaller 
cubes, no two of which are congruent (see first link). 
One is tempted to make a wild guess that this might have 
something to do with Fermat's last theorem (however obvious 
it seems that there could be no actual relation).

Incomplete history: Roland Sprague published in 1940 the 
first simple squared square 
[link](http://www.squaring.net/history_theory/sprague.html). 
He used squared rectangles found earlier by Zbigniew Moroń, 
plus additional squares. Another important early work was by 
R.L. Brooks, C.A.B. Smith, A.H. Stone and W.T.Tutte 
[link](http://www.squaring.net/sq/ss/spss/spss.html) who 
related the problem to electrical networks (graphs).

Another post about squared squares is 
[link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145356/whats-the-best-way-to-characterise-the-distribution-of-prime-elements-in-simple) 
it has some related numerical data.

Comment: As discussed after my incomplete solution:  The answer is yes if we have 25 mutually disjoint perfect squared squares of some order.  This page discusses disjoint families: http://www.squaring.net/sq/sr/spsr/spsr_dnt.html.  All indications are that a family of 25 should exist.  But, unfortunately, I see no elementary way to get the family (although at first I thought it should be easy via compound squares).

Comment: The tables at squaring.net might already have 25 suitable mutually disjoint squares, of various orders but same side length, though I do not know how to filter this information out.

Comment: What we could really use is, for each square, a list of multiples of that square which are mutually disjoint.  With enough such examples, we can recursively split up squares into smaller and smaller squares and guarantee they are all disjoint.

Comment: Mirko: a formal comment. It's a bit hard for me to read a term like *perfect squared square*. Could you replace it with ***psquare***--it'd really help me, and perhaps others would not mind?

Comment: @ Wlodzimierz [`Here`](http://www.squaring.net/sq/ss/ss.html) abbreviations SPSS and CPSS are used for _Simple Perfect Squared Squares_ and _Compound Perfect Squared Squares_, seems a standard terminology. So my question is about PSS (without specifying SPSS or CPSS, but assuming, as the following discussion shows, that CPSS are fine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question.  This is not (any longer) an answer, but a strategy.

First, try to construct 25 mutually disjoint squared squares of the same order.  Then arrange them according to a 3,4,5 template.

I initially thought that the 25 mutually disjoint squares should be an easy construction and followed from varying a pair of disjoint squares inside of a larger squared square.  But distinctness of the little squares seems tricky to enforce.

Even if this works, I admit it is unsatisfactory.  The example squares will be huge and (badly) compound.  Simple squares are better.

Incidentally, construction of disjoint squared squares of the same order (number of constituents) and size seems to be a challenging problem;
see http://www.squaring.net/sq/sr/spsr/spsr_dnt.html

Edit by Mirko: As indicated in comments below, it is enough to find nine (or even eight) mutually disjoint PSS of the same size. The list of order 25 SPSS at 
http://www.squaring.net/sq/ss/spss/o25/spsso25.html 
includes eight squares of size $293,311,317,367,373,421,503,541$, 
which are all prime numbers. (For $421$ and $541$ each, there are versions 
A and B, but we only take version A.) Let $M=293\cdot 311\cdot 317\cdot 367\cdot 373\cdot 421\cdot 503\cdot 541 =$ $453011799002853190123$. 
Inflate each of the above eight squares by the product of the sizes 
of the other seven squares, e.g. inflate the square with size 
$293$ by a factor of $311\cdot 317\cdot 367\cdot 373\cdot 421\cdot 503\cdot 541 =$ $M/293 =$ $1546115354958543311$, and similarly 
for the other sizes. We obtain eight PSS, say $K_1,...,K_8$, each of size $M$. 
They are mutually disjoint, e.g. the side of none of the squares in the partitioning of 
$K_1$ is divisible by $293$, whereas the side of each square in 
the partitioning of each of $K_2,...,K_8$ is divisible by $293$. 
So we could put together $K_1,...,K_8$, plus a square of side $M$, 
and a square of side $4 M$ to form a CPSS of side (=size) $5 M$. 
Clearly it splits into one PSS of size $4M$ (and of order $1$ ... 
what a cheat), and another CPSS of size $3M$ (and as it happens, 
of order $8\cdot 25 +1= 201$). To make this a bit less of a cheat, we could start with nine primes, that is add e.g. $547$ to the above list, and redefine 
$M=293\cdot 311\cdot 317\cdot 367\cdot 373\cdot 421\cdot 503\cdot 541 \cdot 547=$ $247797454054560694997281$. We get 
$K_1,...,K_8,K_9$ in a similar way as before, but now, in addition, inflate $K_9$ by a factor of four and use the result in place of the single square of size $4 M$.

Thank you for all contributions!

Comment: Well, a _simple square_ doesn't have to be a simple example ;) Your proof shows there are infinitely many Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ that are sides of perfect squared squares $A,B,C$, respectively, where $C$ may be compound, and is built from the squares forming $A$ and $B$ ... actually are there infinitely many that are essentially different (no common factor)? A computer search may work, but it may also be slow, if large numbers are involved: It might be interesting if one could find any shortcuts to help the computer.

Comment: I hesitated, initially, when I read step (2), but since 1429 is a prime, it seemed in this case it presented no problems. So I did not follow why you needed a large square: You need to get at least 25 squares, so it is enough if $S$ is formed by at least 5 squares (since $2^5=32 > 25$), but this is a vacuous requirement since the Lowest-order perfect squared square has 21 squares, well above 5. Perhaps it is not as easy and I am missing something, will review it again. I am starting to question what was the relevance of 1429 being a prime ...

Comment: I no longer follow (2), neither what I meant in my previous comment. What I had "understood", was that given any one of the 25 squares, the "inflated" squares inside _it_ are mutually disjoint (which is easy using 1429 is a prime), and not that these 25 squares are _mutually_ disjoint 
... I do not see how to get the latter, even if $S$ is large. Of course, if the 25 squares are not _mutually_ disjoint then this solution would not be interesting: We could as well have split 5x5 into 3x3+4x4, if we allowed repetitions of the same building block. I do not even follow your idea in (2).

Comment: Yes... I am concerned too.  I am thinking about a fix to easily get the 25 squares.

Comment: It just occurred to me that our 25 squares don't need to be of the same order (number of constituent squares) -- just the same size.

Comment: Take any 25 simple squared squares $S_1,...,S_{25}$, of different sizes (though same sizes might be allowed, provided in this case the squares are disjoint), so anyway say the sizes are different: $s_1,...,s_{25}$. Let $M$ be the least common multiple of the $s_k$ (though _least_ need not be essential). Let $c_k=M/s_k$, for each $k$. Inflate each square $S_k$ by a factor $c_k$ so the inflated square has size $s_k\cdot c_k = M$, that is we ended with 25 squares of the same size $M$. The question is whether we could do this, keeping the resulting squares mutually disjoint.

Comment: You don't need 25, just 9 of the same size and one that is four times the size.  Again a cheat, but with fewer requirements.  Also, one of the nine need only be a single square.

Comment: Further, the construction should work if you can find 9 (mutually co)primes that are the sides of integral squared squares.

Comment: Say $S,T$ are PSS (perfect squared squares) of size $s,t$. We want to _make_ them disjoint, keeping $s/t$ constant, as follows. First zoom in, i.e. multiply each $S$ and $T$ by the same factor $c$ (e.g. the size of some PSS $C$). Then replace each (or some) constituent square of $T$ with a PSS (e.g. using $C$, though there may be other ways). Do this finitely many times, if necessary (zoom into $S,T$, then refine $T$), till the largest square in the modified $T$ is smaller than the smallest square in the modified $S$. _Is it possible_ to do this, so in the end the modified $T$ remains perfect?

Comment: @Peter I edited your answer further.

Answer (score 2):

Mirko's solution is of order 226, A solution of order 202 can be constructed with a different choice of SPSSs (from http://www.squaring.net/ ).
The five order 22 SPSSs with sides 110(A), 139, 154, 172 and 192, together with the three order 23 SPSSs with sides 188, 208 and 257, are mutually disjoint (with a total of 179 subsquares). To see this, express the side of each subsquare as a fraction of the side of the SPSS. List the denominators associated with each SPSS. The only one associated with more than one SPSS is 16, for 22:192A and 23:208A, but those SPSSs are mutually disjoint. Let M be the LCM of the sizes of the eight SPSSs. We can put together these eight SPSSs, each of side 7M, a square of side 7M, and SPSS 22:147A of side 28M to form a CPSS of side 35M. It can be split into the order 22 SPSS of side 28M and an order 180 CPSS of side 21M.

Answer (score 2):

My 2nd example is a PSS of order 90 with side 14137200.
Let k = lcm(110,112,135,136) = 2827440. Multiply the elements of SPSSs 22:110A and 21:112A by 25704 and 75735 respectively, and of SPSRs 22:272x136 and 23:270x135 (the one with corner square 70) by 20790 and 41888 respectively. This gives SPSSs with sides k and 3k, and SPSRs 2k x k and 4k x 2k. Together with squares with sides k and 2k, the pieces tile an order 90 CPSS of side 5k or, alternatively, the order 21 SPSS with side 3k and an order 69 CPSS with side 4k.
The 2x1 SPSRs can be found in A. J. W. Duijvestijn's "Simple Perfect Squared Squares and 2x1 Squared Rectangles of Orders 21 to 24", J. Combinatorial Theory, Series B 59, 26-34 (1993) at http://doc.utwente.nl/17948/1/Duijvestijn93simple.pdf
My 3rd example is a PSS of order 77 with side 1054680.
Let k = 210936. Create (1) a CPSR 3k x k by juxtaposing SPSRs 14:533x376A and 15:595x376A and multiplying their elements by 561; (2) an SPSR 2k x k from 22:272x136 by multiplying its elements by 1551; (3) a perfect squared hexagon (a square 4k x 4k with a k x k square missing from a corner) by removing corner element 66 from SPSS 25:264C and multiplying its other elements by 3196. These three pieces, together with two squares (sides k and 2k), form an order 77 CPSS with side 5k or, alternatively, the order 25 SPSS with side 4k and an order 52 CPSS with side 3k.
The lowest order of a 3x1 PSR may be 26, which may enable an example of order 74 to be constructed.

Comment: Marvelous! A [`related problem`](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240277/minimum-number-of-integer-sided-squares-needed-to-tile-an-m-by-n-rectangle/246948) on squaring of rectangles with an asnwer from the same person at mathstackexchange.